# Aumentar un mes a una fecha con SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy trabajando en una función en SQL que aumente un mes a una fecha determinada (`@FECHA`), considerando que, si la fecha resultante es día inhábil se sumen los días (sábado o domingo, o ambos según corresponda) y comience en día lunes(hábil).

**Código SQL**

```
DECLARE @FECHA AS DATETIME  
SET @FECHA = '2016-11-14 08:09:48.507' --ejemplo con cálculo incorrecto
SET @FECHA = '2016-11-16 08:09:48.507' --ejemplo con cálculo correcto

CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,@FECHA)<15 
    THEN CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,14,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0,@FECHA),0))) 
    
ELSE 

    CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,14,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0,DATEADD(MM,1,@FECHA)),0))) END) >= 4 
        THEN DATEADD(DAY,(6 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,@FECHA)<15 
        THEN CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,14,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0,@FECHA),0))) 

ELSE 
    CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,14,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0,DATEADD(MM,1,@FECHA)),0))) END)),
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,@FECHA)<15 
    THEN CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,14,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0,@FECHA),0))) 

ELSE 
    CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,14,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0,DATEADD(MM,1,@FECHA)),0))) END)

ELSE 
    DATEADD(DAY,-1*((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,@FECHA)<15 
    THEN CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,14,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0,@FECHA),0))) 
    
ELSE 
    CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,14,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0,DATEADD(MM,1,@FECHA)),0))) END))+2),
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,@FECHA)<15 
    THEN CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,14,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0,@FECHA),0))) 
ELSE 
    CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,14,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0,DATEADD(MM,1,@FECHA)),0))) END) END AS FECHARESULTANTE
```

**Hasta el momento mi resultado es correcto cuando en `@FECHA`, el día de la fecha es mayor a 15, pero cuando este es menor a 15, se está haciendo incorrecto el cálculo.**

Comment: mysql o sql server? igual no termino de entender todo tu codigo... no es muchisimo mas simple sumar un mes, comprobar si es sabado o domingo, y sumar 1 o 2 dias dependiendo de eso? que son todos esos if????

Answer (score 1):

Como menciona el compañero en el comentario es más fácil sumar el día y verificar si el día es sábado o domingo y sumar 1 o 2.

Aquí hay 2 ejemplos de funciones que hace eso. La se asume que @@DATEFIRST es 1.

```
-----POR DÍA---------
CREATE FUNCTION NEXT_WEEKDAY(@date as DATE, @days as INT =1) RETURNS DATE 
AS
BEGIN


DECLARE @nextDate AS DATE = DATEADD(DAY, @days, @date)
DECLARE @weekday AS INT = DATEPART(dw, @nextDate)

RETURN IIF(@weekday<=5, 
           @nextDate, --dia entre semana, no hacer nada
           DATEADD(DAY, @weekday%5%2+1, @nextDate)-- fin de semana, agregar 1 o 2 según el día
           )

END

-----------------POR MES -------------

CREATE FUNCTION NEXT_MONTH_WEEKDAY(@date as DATE, @months as INT = 1) RETURNS DATE 
AS
BEGIN


DECLARE @nextDate AS DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, @months, @date)
DECLARE @weekday AS INT = DATEPART(dw, @nextDate)

RETURN IIF(@weekday<=5, 
           @nextDate, --dia entre semana, no hacer nada
           DATEADD(DAY, @weekday%5%2+1, @nextDate)-- fin de semana, agregar 1 o 2 según el día
           )

END
```

Para utilizar la funciones:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;

SELECT [dbo].[NEXT_WEEKDAY](GETDATE(), DEFAULT)

SELECT DBO.[NEXT_MONTH_WEEKDAY](GETDATE(), DEFAULT);
```